# нет доступа: git pull

Tags: git, консоль, виртуальная-машина, репозиторий, git-pull

Есть виртуальная машина(ВМ) в облаке и вчера весь день мучился, чтобы загрузить репозиторий с github так как опыта работы с ней мало как и с работой git + терминал. В итоге понял, что надо было создавать отдельный ssh ключ для ВМ и как-то подвязывать его к репозиторию github. По итогу получилось локально на моем компьютере(Mac OS) запушить проект и с помощью git clone загрузить его на ВМ.
Сегодня обнаружил ошибку в коде, изменил локально, запушил изменения, захожу в ВМ, пишу git pull и получаю ошибку:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

после недолгого поиска по форумам везде писали, что это возникает так как нет ssh ключа и надо делать новый и подвязывать его к github. и многим такой способ помогал так как действительно у них не было ssh ключа изначально. у меня же он есть(иначе бы я вчера не склонировал бы свой непубличный репозиторий).
подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за ошибка и как её решить?

**UPD:** удалось решить проблему путём удаления ключа и создания нового. после исправлений отвлекся на свои дела и сессия выключилась(видимо таймаут из-за бездействия) и снова не работает git pull. видимо снова придется удалять ключ и новый ставить. кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

**UPD2:**
путь от попытки пулла до генерации ключа и нового пулла. всё это делается на удаленной ВМ

```
$ git pull
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ rm -rf my_current_key
$ rm -rf my_current_key.pub
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail@mail.com"
> Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
> Enter file in which to save the key (/home/sharkavli/.ssh/id_ed25519): new_key
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 43475
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/new_key
$ cd ~/my_project
$ git pull
>  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ cd backend
$ npm run dev
```

спустя некоторое время сессия может закрыться и мне снова придется удалять ключ и генерировать новый.

Comment: `make sure you have the correct access rights` - проверил права своего ключа?

Comment: @ESkri , нет, не проверял. как это сделать? и почему такое могло возникнуть(недостаточно прав)? я выпускал обычный ssh ключ(по классической инструкции на гитхабе) и по нему как-то же уже получал доступ к своему репозиторию для загрузки своего проекта.

Comment: гитхаб любит дробить права доступа.  clone и pull - это разные галочки в правах.

Comment: @ESkri , спасибо за разъяснения: я такого не знал. не подскажешь как узнать какие права есть? и как поменять уровень доступа?

Comment: В вопросе не хватает последовательности команд, приводящих к заявленному результату. Ключи ssh просто так не протухают и пересоздавать их каждый раз нет необходимости.

Comment: @user7860670 , почему же? я же сказал: `git pull` приводит к такому результату. в целом я терминалом почти не пользуюсь. в основном я использую команды `npm run start` и `git pull`. ну и в добавок открываю папки, просматриваю файлы свои на ВМ.
сейчас произошло следующее: я подключаюсь к ВМ по команде `ssh myusername@my.ip`, ввожу свой пароль(fingerprint) и включаю сервер. потом останавливаю, исправляю локально ошибки, пушу на гит и пытаюсь сделать `git pull` новой версии, но он мне не дал.

Comment: ¿Так а где последовательность действий, которыми гит получил возможность использовать ssh ключ? ¿Где этот ключ, какие конфиги ssh? ¿Как это все настраивалось?

Comment: @user7860670 не понимаю вашего вопроса. вы про команды? или конкретно мои действия?

Comment: Описывайте всю последовательность своих действий с момента генерации ключа до вызова git pull. Включая все команды с их выводом. [mcve]

Comment: @user7860670 дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: Теперь все понятно. У вас протухает сессия с запущенным ssh-agent, вот ключ и перестает подхватывается. Вместо использования ssh-agent отредактируйте конфиг ssh https://gist.github.com/rbialek/1012262 чтобы тот знал, какой ключ надо использовать для гитхаба

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за разъяснение. однако мне не совсем понятна терминология. что значит "ключ не подхватывается"? если я правильно вас понял, то вы имеете ввиду то, что ключ в новой сессии(а равно переподключение к ВМ) теряет свою актуальность?

Comment: Ключ актуальность не теряет. Однако если не запущен ssh-agent (и если конфиг ssh не отредактирован), то когда git пытается подключиться по ssh к гитхабу, то не знает, где взять правильный ключ. А один раз отредактировать конфиг ssh проще, чем каждый раз запускать ssh-agent. Причем этот совет распространяется на ssh вообще, не только в контесте git.

Comment: @user7860670 создал файл `.config`, вписал те параметры, что советовали на форуме в приведенной вами ссылке, но это не сработало. возможно стоило назвать файл `config`? так как именно такое название я видел чаще, но сделал все-таки по инструкции, которая, как я заметил, многим помогла

Comment: Файл называется `config`, а путь `.ssh/config`. Там в заголовке опечатка.