# Проблемы с ssh-key в GitHub

Tags: github, ssh-key

Как вы настраивайте ssh-ключи и потом уже созданный проект пушите в уже созданный репозиторий , проблема такая создал private репозиторий, потом пытаюсь туда запушить проект пишет permission denied , ну я снегенировал новый ключ через ssh-keygen потом eval "$(ssh-agent -$)" потом ssh-add id_ed22519_git потом скопировал ключ и в самом гитхаб его добавил , пишут ssh -T git@github.com пишет что успешно авторизован , потом возвращаюсь в проект пытаюсь пушить  он опять говорит что permission denied , я возвращаюсь в терминал опять пишу ssh -T git@github.com и пишет permission denied , чо это может быть? У меня arch Linux  если что

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555694#comment2802315_1555694