Проблемы с git push
Учусь на яндекс практикуме. Делал проект с код ревью, который необходимо отправлять на Git.
Делал в точности как описано в инструкции:

Форкнул репозиторий с учетки практикума на гите в свою учетку. Она начала отображаться в списке моих репозиториев.
В терминале git bash через команду git clone... в VS Code скопировал репозиторий из своей учетки локально на пк.
Сделал проект. Через git commit... коммичу все изменения, которые сделал. Все проходит ок.
На этапе git push origin main все стопорится. Пишет будто я пытаюсь запушить изменения в репозиторий практикума, а не в свой.

Скрины ошибок прилагаю



Ошибки надо прикладывать не скринами, а текстом )

Раз так пишет, значит, так и есть

В инструкции еще где-то должны быть пункты для настройки авторизации для дальнего сервера git (создание и прописывание ssh ключа и т.п.). "Скрины ошибок прилагаю" - не делайте так

У меня настроены ключи, авторизация прописана. Не совсем понял где я могу вставить урл на репозиторий в своем гите???

Оно так не работает. Еслы вы утверждаете, что авторизация прописана, что пушите в свой репозиторий и что вылезает ошибка доступа, то это значит, что одно из ваших утверждений неверно. Для проверки списка дальних репозиториев используйте команду git remote -v.  И еще убедитесь, что для авторизации не использовали ssh-agent на каком-то этапе.

А если использовался? Авторизоваться заново без ssh?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555694/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-git-pull#comment2802315_1555694

Попробуйте заменить в проекте origin url на свой (ссылку на свой репозиторий в гите)
git remote set-url origin you.git.url/here

